# intercepting response with substring in url using playwright

Tags: python, playwright

I have been learning playwright on python, but it appears that I cannot get it to successfully find a response whose URL contains a substring, while on node I am indeed able to do so, is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
async with page.expect_response("*") as response:
    if "getVerify" in response.url:
        print("found")
```

i have also tried using `getVerify` and `in` to no avail.

node code:

```
page.on('response', response => {
    if (response.url().includes('getVerify')) {
        console.log(response.url())
```

Answer (score 0):

With the node case, it's a bit different as you're passively subscribing to an event. In the python snippet, you are basically doing the equivalent of [page.waitForResponse](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response). Typically you'll do that in conjunction with some action that triggers the response (such as submitting a form).

Try using the python [page.on](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-event-response) API. Like this:

```py
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

def check_response(response):
    print(response.url)
    if 'getVerify' in response.url:
        print("Response URL: ", response.url)

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch()
        page = await browser.new_page()
        page.on("response", check_response)
        await page.goto("http://playwright.dev")
        print(await page.title())
        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```